# Upgrading Win7/Quantal(secure boot off) to Win8/Quantal dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, secure-boot

I have a Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot setup on an HP g4 laptop that is Win8 ready. Secure boot is off(using legacy boot).

I want to upgrade to Windows 8, keeping the Ubuntu 12.10 install intact (until 13.04!). What is the best way to go about it - any caveats, issues I might encounter etc would be great. Can secure boot be enabled, and what are the benefits? (I read through its description, but I want to know practical benefits).

Comment: This has been asked before.  Typical process would be do an upgrade installation from `Windows 7` to `Windows 8` then fix GRUB2 boot menu or add your Ubuntu installation to the Windows 8 boot menu your choice.

Comment: Backup all your important files first on Windows as well as Linux.

Comment: I've reinstalled Windows after Ubuntu, so I'm familiar with repairing GRUB2. What I want to know is if/should I use secure boot, or turn it off and use legacy boot etc.